# preg_match to extract mailto on anchor

Tags: php, regex, anchor, preg-match, mailto

I need to get the email adress from an anchor with a mailto attribute with regex.

this pattern: `(.*)<a\s(.*?)(.*)\s*href\=['"]mailto:([-a-z0-9_]+)@([a-z0-9-]+).([a-z]+)['"]>(.*)</a>(.*)`

Works in regex coach though it doesnt work with PHP.

Code:

```
preg_match("'(.*)<a (.*?)(.*) *href\=['\"]mailto:([-a-z0-9_]+)@([a-z0-9-]+).([a-z]+)['\"]>(.*)</a>(.*)'si", "<a href=\"mailto:someemail@ohio.com\"">Some email</a>", $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

So why doenst it work in php?

Comment: As a side note: you'll need to add `+` as a character in your character class :([-a-z0-9_]+) because some folks use them for filtering triggers in email addresses eg foo+bar@devnull.nz

Comment: All these `.*` will result in a horrible performance behavior.

Comment: side note: although rare, it is perfectly acceptable to have an email address like: hell.o\@world@two.ats.com You might be better off shooting for a more simple regex, unless there is some security concern with the emails. Depends what you are doing with em.

Comment: @Gumbo would `.*$` do it? basically all till end of line?

Comment: @DampeS8N: No, `hell.o\@world@example.com` is invalid (both for `\‍` and `@`). But `"hell.o@world"@example.com` is valid.

Comment: `"` will be url-encoded in the HTML attribute.

Comment: @stillstanding: Will it? What if single quotes were used?

Comment: @Gumbo: And most of the parsers I have just found to check all this say both are wrong. This is exactly why emails suck.

Comment: @Gumbo: I meant to say "should", else the HTML will be incorrectly parsed

Comment: @DampeS8N: There is a difference between the syntax as it is defined in the specification and the syntax that is actually used/allowed.

Comment: @stillstanding: No, `<a href='"foo bar"@example.com'>` is just fine.

Comment: @Gumbo: That's no problem. But something like `<a href="<?php echo $email; ?>">` will run into trouble if `$email='"hell.o@world"@example.com';`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[PHP’s PCRE](http://php.net/pcre) require the regular expression to be wrapped into [delimiters](http://php.net/regexp.reference.delimiters) that separate the pattern from optional [modifiers](http://php.net/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers). In this case the first non-alphanumeric character is used (i.e. `'`) so the pattern is actually just `(.*)<a (.*?)(.*) *href\=[` and the rest are treated as modifiers. And that is an invalid regular expression as the `[` is not properly escaped and the rest are not valid modifiers neither.

As the others have already suggested, you can fix this by escaping any occurrence of the delimiter `'` inside the regular expression or choose a different delimiter that does not appear in the regular expression.

But besides that, trying to parse HTML with regular expressions is very error prone. In you case using that many `.*` will also result in a horrible performance behavior (it’s just due to how regular expressions are processed).

Better use a proper HTML parser that returns a DOM that can be queried like [PHP’s DOM library](http://php.net/dom):

```
$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($str);
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName("a") as $a) {
    if ($a->hasAttribute("href")) {
        $href = trim($a->getAttribute("href"));
        if (strtolower(substr($href, 0, 7)) === 'mailto:') {
            $components = parse_url($href);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: -1. Answer the specific question, _then_ lecture about why DOM is better. It may not be trivial for the asker to understand the new library or refactor their situation quickly enough no matter how much we may feel that there's a better way.

Comment: @Shabbyrobe: I’ve added an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Your delimiter is a quote `'`, and there are some instances of it in the regex:

```
preg_match("'(.*)<a (.*?)(.*) *href\=['\"]mailto:([-a-z0-9_]+)@([a-z0-9-]+).([a-z]+)['\"]>(.*)</a>(.*)'si", "<a href=\"mailto:someemail@ohio.com\"">Some email</a>", $matches);
                                      ^                                              ^
```

Escape them (i.e.: `\'`) or change your delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match('#<a\s.*?href=[\'"]mailto:([A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6})[\'"].*?>.*?</a>#i', $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[0];
} else {
    $result = "";
}
```

Comment: This fails for something like `<a name="…">…</a><map name="…"><area href="…" alt="…"></map<a href="mailto:user@example.com">…</a>`.