# php - preg_replace all maito: tags with the email address

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

similar to this question:

[preg_match to extract mailto on anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258435/preg-match-to-extract-mailto-on-anchor)

but I am trying to do a **global** string replace in php that will convert:

..href="mailto:jeff@mycom.com">Mailme<... (including the "a" tags)

to only "jeff@mycom.com" with no tags. This needs to be a replace, not an extract.

I have been using preg_replace, but like so many others, am rather poor at regex. It's the regex I'm really after, but best practice is welcome as long as the final solution is clear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 

$html = '<a href="mailto:jeff@mycom.com">Mailme</a> (including the "a" tags)';
$html = preg_replace("~<a .*?href=[\'|\"]mailto:(.*?)[\'|\"].*?>.*?</a>~", "$1", $html);
echo $html;
```

[working demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/3990f.php)

Comment: thank you  - knew this wasn't a hard one, just lacking in regex skills

Comment: @K6t: it search everything till first occurence of href. If you would have <a href= href= code, without ? it would show everything from <a to last href

Answer (score 0):

following regex will do work for you.

```
 preg_replace(/<a .*?href=((?:\'|\"))mailto:(.*?)$1[^>]*>[^<]+</a>/i, "$2", $html);
```

use [^<]+ between start and end tag because some it may happened that line breaks occur in html, so .* will fail there, [^<]+ this fail in rare case when (less than sign) < appears in tag content. Used flag "i" for in-case sensitivity replace.