# preg_match, fail to get email address

Tags: php, preg-match

I need to retrieve email data from below html code

```
<a href="mailto:contact@rovio.com" rel="nofollow">Email Developer</a>
```

I have used this code to get email address, but it failed to get it.

```
preg_match('@^(?:mailto:)?([^/]+)@i', $data, $matches);
$email = $matches[1];
echo $email;
```

Can you see what is the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258435/preg-match-to-extract-mailto-on-anchor

Answer (score 0):

What you just can do is

- just strip mailto: from the href attribute
- then filter the mail adress

---

```
$string = '<a href="mailto:contact@rovio.com" rel="nofollow">Email Developer</a>';
$parsing = new SimpleXmlElement($string);
$attrs = (array)$parsing->attributes();
$mail = str_replace('mailto:','',$attrs['href']);
if(filter_var($mail,FILTER_VALIATE_MAIL)){//if it is a good email
   //goooo
}
```